# How to treat a Beaucarnea recurvata wounded at the base of the trunk?

Tags: plant-health, plant-recommendations, plant-care, transplanting, damage

I have recently relocated a [Beaucarnea recurvata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaucarnea_recurvata) in the garden.

In the process the plant got wounded and I am worried about its survival. Earlier the ball ([caudex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caudex)) was in contact with a 2 feet wooden plant, its roots were going through it and then reached soil.

During the shifting it got detached from the wooden plant and at its new location the plant is in direct contact with the soil. What should I do to make sure this plant survives?

You can see the wounds in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do about the wound - once, wound paint would have been recommended, but current evidence suggests this increases the risk of problems, so its use is no longer advised.

Your question is a little unclear - when you say 'wooden plant', I'm assuming you mean a wooden planter, through which the roots had penetrated at the bottom and that meant you had to plant it in the ground. You may need to ensure you water it for a few weeks until the roots settle in and start recovering.